# Magento preference not working for Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem

Tags: magento2

Can anyone explain please why this preference is not working.

I am trying to override the Filesystem class methods but preference not working.

RWD\ParentChild\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem" type="RWD\ParentChild\Rave\Filesystem" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to override a class with a preference that is not really used directly.

Depending on what you want to achieve, there might - or might not - be a better solution.

##### Preference required before ObjectManager is instantiated

If you want to modify the loading of the dependency injection configuration, your preference won't work as Magento directly instantiates `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom` which extends `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem` and uses that to load the DI configuration.

This is for example a snippet where no object manager is used for instantiation (and also `Fileystem` is not directly used, see next section):

```
// vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php, line 273
...
$reader = new \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom(
    $fileResolver,
    $argumentMapper,
    $schemaLocator,
    $validationState
);
...
```

##### Preference on parent instead of used implementation

In other places in Magento, a child class is used instead of the `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem` class itself. An example would be `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config\Reader`:

```
...
class Reader extends \Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem
{
...
```

A preference cannot modify a PHP *extends* as the extended type is not depending on the ObjectManager, it's plain PHP. It's using the fully qualified class name from the inline specification or the `use` statement.

This means:

- You cannot use preferences to override usages of a type that has been created inline using PHPs `new` keyword
- You cannot replace a type that is only used "indirect". So if only sub-types like `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config\Reader` instead of `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem` are used, you cannot create a preference for `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem`.

What you can do now:

- To adjust something before the ObjectManager has been initialized, a Composer patch is an option. Note that this isn't really a good solution
- Find out what is the real type you want to create a preference for (e. g. `\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config\Reader` instead of `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem`, as `Reader` extends `Filesystem`.
- Try to solve the problem with plugins, events, arguments, and virtual types in your di.xml instead of user preferences. Preferences should be avoided to override things when possible.